# Cxfreeze not copy Qt6 Styles in mingw-w64

Tags: python, user-interface, mingw-w64, msys2, pyqt6

I Installed PyQt6 and cxfreeze on msys2-mingw-w64

But After Compiling python file, shown in console Just ['Windows', 'Fusion'] Style

here is setup.py of cxfreeze

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {'packages': [], 'excludes': []}

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [ Executable('un.py', base=base)]

setup(name='qt',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables = executables)
```

And The python file:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory().keys()) # Print Available Qt6 Styles

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 260, 731, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 380, 371, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Win"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I Tried to copy `C:\msys2\mingw64\usr\share\qt6\plugins` to Output EXE Directory and`lib\PyQt6`.

Comment: Can you explain "but nothing is happen" in a little more detail?
Error message? Program exit code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable QT_PLUGIN_PATH, for example in a Command Prompt, before running the EXE file, like this:

```
SET QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\msys2\mingw64\usr\share\qt6\plugins
```

You can also run the EXE files that are not working through [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if any dependency DLL files are missing. Because you definitely have them all in the same folder as the EXE files (e.g. DLLs from Qt and all its dependencies).

I wrote a tool as part of the [pedeps](https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps) project to copy dependency DLL files along with EXE file(s) (`copypedeps -r`). You can use that to automatically copy all dependencies.